# Asterisk with new functions

Tags: sql, function, odbc, asterisk

I created a write func odbc list records files in sql table:

```
[R]

dsn=connector

write=INSERT INTO ast_records (filename,caller,callee,dtime) VALUES
('${ARG1}','${ARG2}','${ARG3}','${ARG4}')

prefix=M
```

and set it in dialplan :

```
exten => _0X.,n,Set(
M_R(${MIXMONITOR_FILENAME}\,${CUSER}\,${EXTEN}\,${DTIME})= )
```

when I excute it I get an error : ast_func_write: M_R Function not registered:

note that : asterisk with ***windows***

Answer (score 5):

1. First thing I saw was you were performing the call to the function incorrectly...you need to be assigning values, not arguments....try this:

   func_odbc.conf:

   ```
   [R]
   dsn=connector
   prefix=M
   writesql=INSERT INTO ast_records (filename,caller,callee,dtime) VALUES('${VAL1}','${VAL2}','${VAL3}','${VAL4}');
   ```

   dialplan:

   ```
   exten => _0X.,1,Set(M_R()=${MIXMONITOR_FILENAME}\,${CUSER}\,${EXTEN}\,${DTIME})
   ```

   If that doesn't help you, continue on in my list :)
2. Make sure func_odbc.so is being loaded by Asterisk. (from the asterisk CLI: module show like func_odbc)... If it's not loaded, it can't "build" your custom odbc query function.
3. Make sure your DSN is configured in /etc/odbc.ini
4. Make sure that /etc/asterisk/res_odbc.conf is properly configured
5. Make sure you're calling the DSN by the right name (I see it happen all the time)
6. enable verbose and debug in your Asterisk logging, do a logger reload, core set verbose 5, core set debug 5, and then try the call again. when the call finishes, review the log, you'll see much more output regarding what happened...

Regarding the answer from recluze...Not to call you out here, but using a PHP AGI is serious overkill here. The func_odbc function works just fine, why create more overhead and potential security issues by calling an external script (which has to use a interpreter program on TOP itself)?

Answer (score 2):

you should call func odbc function as "ODBC_connector". connector should be use in the func_odbc.conf file [connector]. In the dialplan it should call like this.

```
exten=> _0x.,n,ODBC_connector(${arg1},${arg2})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the syntax you're trying to use but how about using AGI (with php) for this. Just define your logic in a php script and call it from your dialplan as:

```
exten => _0X.,n,AGI(script-filename.php,${CUSER},${EXTEN},${DTIME})
```